# Error using the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard, SqlServer.Types v15

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

After upgrading to VS 2017 15.9.2 i get the following error when trying to save the changes after using the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard.

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=15.0.0.0 ......... Could not find the file"

If I edit the dataset using the designer and try to add a Column to a tableadapter, I get the same error.

Have no errors running the project, its only the designer that does not work.

This error persists even if I start a new project.

Checking under "C:\Windows\assembly", I only have version 12 and 13 installed. However, checking nuget, the latest version is 14.0.1016.290?

How can i change the version the wizard/designer is using? Or where can I get the version 15?

Comment: I have VS 15.9.2 installed and I just checked my GAC and I have versions 12, 13, 14 and 15 of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types installed.  It sounds like something has gone wrong with the installation so I would suggest a repair. If you run the VS Installer then you should see 'Modify' and 'Launch' buttons and a 'More' drop-down to the right. That's what I've got for VS Pro anyway. The 'Repair' option is under that 'More' drop-down.

Comment: A repair did the trick, have version 15 installed now.